# Tracking new @mentions

Tags: quip, liveapps

Our team plans to make an extension for Chrome to track new @mentions in our team QUIP. We studied the API documentation, but unfortunately we didn’t find anything about tracking new tasks or mentions. Could you advise me how to track of this objects via API?

Comment: Are you going to track Salesforce Task records or QUIP only records? And mentions are also in Salesforce chatter?

Comment: We need tracking only QUIP @mentions via API.